# Monomac Copy and Paste

Tags: c#, mono, monomac

I am able to get the contents of an object into the pasteboard, but how do I get the contents of the pasteboard into an object?

Here's the code I am using for putting the contents in.

```
private static string[] pboardTypes = { "NSStringPboardType" };
NSPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard.DeclareTypes(pboardTypes, null);
NSPasteboard.GeneralPasteboard.SetStringForType("Contents", pboardTypes[0]);
```

Using Monomac and C# thanks.

Comment: My fault! I had removed the edit menu from main menu.